# Passing Node.js varaibles from back-edn to front-end using express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, variables

I would like to pass the IP variable obtained from `request.headers['x-forwarded-for']` in my server.js file to my webpage index.html and displaying it. I have tried passing it in the `<script>` tag and even within the  tag to display it immediately. That is my script now:

**server.js:**

```
    const express = require('express')
    const server = express()
    const engine = require('consolidate');
        server.engine('html', engine.mustache);
        server.use(express.static('./'));
            server.get("/", function (request, response) {
    clientIP = request.headers['x-forwarded-for']
    response.render(__dirname + "/index.html", {
        ip: clientIP
    })
})
```

**index.html:**

```
<body>
    <h1>Wolfram Bot</h1>

    <form method='GET' action="/eval">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="prompt left-pane">
                <span>Enter a command to evaluate:</span>
            </div>

            <br> <br>

            <div class="right-pane">
                <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="" />
                <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="code" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div class="submit-cmd">
            <input type="submit" value="Send Command" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <span>Your IP is begin logged: <a id="ip"></a></span>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>

<script>
    var ip = "<%= name %>"
    console.log(ip)
    document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML = ip
</script>
```

I already red some questions on Google but nothing helped me ;(
here the full code: https://replit.com/@AnonHexo/wolframV3 
Thanking in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Moustache as a template engine (with Consolidate), please check its documentation about how the templating works: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache

I think what you need there is to use `{{ ip }}` in the script like:

```html
<script>
    var ip = "{{ ip }}"
    console.log(ip)
    document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML = ip
</script>
```

Actually, you may want to set the ip right into the html, getting rid of the `<script>` stuff:

```html
<span>Your IP is begin logged: {{ ip }}</span>
```

### Update

I've run locally an example to understand why is not working, and here are my findings:

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const server = express()
const engine = require('consolidate');
const port = 3000;

server.engine('html', engine.mustache);
// set .html as the default extension
server.set('view engine', 'html');
server.set('views', __dirname + '/public');

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const acceptHeader = req.get(`Accept`)
    console.log(`Accepting: ${acceptHeader}`);
    
    res.render(`server`, {
        ip: acceptHeader
    })
})

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I had to set `view engine` and `views` to make it work. Also I had to install mustache, even thou it is not directly used by my code (the docs state that this is a required step).

Now, there is something interesting here: the html file is called `index.html`, and it was loaded by express as the default html when `/` was called, without running my listener at `/`.
This usually happens when the root path is called (`/`), the server tries to load what is in index.html by default, as a static content, and we may not notice the listeners we setup are not being used.
I discovered it when I changed the name of the file to `server.html`.

Now this file, is rendering the dynamic content without javascript, check it out:

**server.html**

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Wolfram Bot</h1>

        <form method='GET' action="/eval">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="prompt left-pane">
                    <span>Enter a command to evaluate:</span>
                </div>

                <br> <br>

                <div class="right-pane">
                    <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="" />
                    <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="code" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="submit-cmd">
                <input type="submit" value="Send Command" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <span>Accept Headers: {{ ip }}</span>
            </div>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, I'm not displaying the IP because it's not always in the request, so I've modified it a bit to display the `Accept` header, but the logic is the same.

Comment: doesn't seems to work, I tried using in in the span and  I get `You IP is begin logged: {{i p }}` and not the actual variable...

Comment: weird, I would first check that the ip is received in the request; then I would try to make the template engine work with a very simple example; finally, put all together

Comment: another option is changing to `ip` instead of `name` in here: `var ip = "<%= name %>"`

Comment: I did and I still don't get my wanted result, I get `Your IP is begin logged: <%= ip %>`

Comment: ok, let me see if I I can reproduce this locally to see exactly what's happening

Comment: allright, I made it run locally and updated the answer with my findings, hope this helps @AnonHexo